# Spring redis cache plain key

Tags: spring, caching, redis

I'm implemented cache with redis for my Spring app. Now I want to run a job to sync data from Mysql to redis every day.
But I got problem that redis key is not human readable text. Eg `userList2:��`
How can I store redis key as plain text when using spring Cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can store values as json using a custom redis template inside cacheManager configuration.

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    return cacheManager;
}
```

Comment: I got error: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: This relates to your KeyGenerator. Please check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3625